# Компиляция NASM под Windows x32 / x64

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

У меня Windows x64. Я хочу написать что-то рабочее (Хоть hello world) на ассемблере под эту систему, используя NASM. Под DosBox всё делается легче лёгкого, скомпилировал, в досбоксе запустил - работает.

```
$ nasm -f bin code.asm -o main.com
```

Под винду - разобраться невозможно, что к чему.
Пробовал:

```
$ nasm -f win64 code.asm -o main.exe
```

Пробовал:

```
$ nasm -f win64 code.asm -o code.o
$ gcc code.o -o main.exe
```

Пробовал:

```
$ nasm -f elf code.asm -o code.o
$ gcc code.o -o main.exe
```

Не работает ничего. Вообще не понимаю, почему нужно использовать компоновщик? Почему код под досбокс - это просто последовательность команд, а код по винду состоит из секций `.text`, `.data` и других...

Для примера, хочу выполнить это на Windows, а не в DosBox:

```
mov ah, 0x2
mov dl, 'X'
int 0x21
ret
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, этот код просто не будет работать на Винде, там не работают прерывания, там нужно импортировать библиотеки и вызывать функции из них.

В x86 есть защита памяти, поэтому программа делится на .data (тут данные) и .text (а тут код). Код можно исполнять, но нельзя писать в него, данные же нельзя исполнять. То есть СМК как в MS-DOS не будет работать, но если сильно захочется, ничто не мешает самостоятельно установить соответствующие флаги секций или воспользоваться функциями API предназначенными для этого.

Так же есть несколько других секций, такие как .rsrc, где хранятся ресурсы (окна, изображения, строки), .import, где указаны импортируемые функции и другие

Для чего нужен компоновщик. Когда компилятор или ассемблер ассемблирует код под Windows, он выдает не готовый машинный код, а объектный файл, объектный файл это машинный код вперемешку с символами, это нужно для того, чтобы к программе можно было прилинковать статическую библиотеку. То есть если в ассемблере встречается какой-то call %внешняя функция%, то в объектном файле указывается имя, а не смещение, компоновщик же берет библиотеку, добавляет ее к коду программы, а потом имя заменяет на смещение.

Таким образом, Windows совсем не MS-DOS, для разных операционных систем код на ассемблере будет отличаться (неужели). Советую почитать книгу Ассемблер для Windows В. Пирогова

Comment: Библиотеки - это именно то, что меня напрягает. Ассемблер - самое низкоуровневое программирование, а я всё равно должен использовать уже кем-то написанный код без понимания того, почему я не могу сам написать содержимое этих библиотек.

Comment: @Don2Quixote, современные операционные системы не позволят вам, например, выводить что-то на экран совсем в обход библиотек. Чтобы понять, как все работает до самого низкого уровня, вам придется писать под DOS, или написать свою ОС. Кстати, `int 21h` - это по сути набор высокоуровневых функций DOS. Чтобы было совсем низкоуровнево - нужно писать напрямую в видеопамять (в защищенном режиме это конечно же не возможно).

Comment: Раз уж на то пошло - что мне начать читать/изучать, чтобы написать на ассемблере приложение не под ОС, а так, чтобы флешку вставил, компьютер включил, в boot menu выбрал флешку, и программа заработала? Чтобы это была просто консоль, в которой я бы мог ввести "ping", а она бы ответила "pong", а дальше я уже что-нибудь придумаю по-умнее.

Comment: @Don2Quixote Руслан Аблязов - Программирование на ассемблере на платформе x86-64 для начала, а так же что-нибудь по программированию BIOS.